# My Laravel installation error on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel, I have installed the Laravel on my localhost using 
WAMP  server but I am getting an error after all steps.

The errors are:

```
( ! ) Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\laravel/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\laravel\index.php on line 21

( ! ) Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\laravel/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\laravel\index.php on line 21
```

[image]
    I have used below link for Laravel installation

```
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows
```

I have tried to debug the issue but haven't found success in the installation.

Please let me know what is missing in installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows), open up the command prompt and `cd` to your directory (or hold Shift while right-clicking on your directory and clicking `Open command window here`) and there run `composer install`.

You can simplify the Laravel installation with Composers [`create-project`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) command.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel path
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel dependencies are not installed yet. That is why it is giving you this error.

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Go to this link and download composer if you haven't already.

Move the composer file to /usr/bin and rename it to just composer.

Go into the root directory of your laravel application. And run:

composer update

This will install and update all required dependencies.

In case you are on windows, which is less likely, but if you are, just download and install composer via the installer and issue the same command in you project's root directory.

Composer is PHP's dependency manager.
In the root directory of your laravel installation you will find a composer.json file. It contains the list of all your project's dependencies. If you ever need to install a package in your project, it becomes very easy. You just have to edit the composer.json file and let it know which package you need. Issuing composer update will install new package listings and update all existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

just to be clear I'm not big fan of wamp.

I've just took quick look at the

```
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows
```

and I suppose laravel framework is not going to work best with point 11 to 14 modifications.

Baseline for laravel to work is you need to http serve /public folder in a properly configured environment (after composer install and create-project as described earlier).

If you want to take full advantage of laravel you need to often cli `php or composer (at least)` efficiently.

While using laravel I suggest installing PHP and MYSQL yourself from scratch (it really takes few minutes) and using convenient IDE (like PHPSTORM for example).

Nowadays PHP has builtin http server, so you don't need any http server in your dev environment.

So in Windows:

1. Install PHP and enable required libraries in php.ini
2. Install and configure local mysql server (easiest way installing via [MySQL installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/))
3. Start development server by invoking `php.exe -S localhost:80 -t "absolute-path-to-your-laravel-installation\public"` like for example `C:\htdocs\laravel\public` via commandLine
4. Enter url in your favorite browser `http://localhost`

Hope that will help to get you started.